# Exception thrown while executing UI block: - [ABI27_0_0RCTview updateContentOffsetINeeded]:

Tags: react-native

I am trying to add drawer navigation to my app. However, I am running into issues and have no clue why they arise. I am following [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7uhJN4kVS6g&t=387s).

1. I am trying to have a navigation drawer with tabs such as home, my profile, settings and so on.

   ```
   const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
     Home: HomeScreen
   }, {
     contentComponent: CustomDrawerComponent
   })
   ```

   When I try and load the Home: HomeScreen for whatever reason the code doesn't load or crashes. However, if I do something like `Login: LoginScreen` or `SignUp: SignUpScreen` the code runs properly and navigates the tabs properly avoiding `Home:HomeScreen`.
2. `<AppDrawerNavigator/>`
   Whenever I put this tag in my return statement between   I get the error of

   > Exception thrown while executing UI block:
   >   [ABI27_0_0RCTview updateContentOffsetINeeded]:

   I don't have the slightest clue what that means and why.
   When I do something in the return such as:

   ```
   <AppDrawerNavigtor>
     <MapView>
     </MapView>
   </AppDrawerNavigtor>
   ```

   the application works and the drawer navigator works with the issues that were brought up in 1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Here is my code. Please excuse its formatting issues.

```
import React from 'react';    
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, KeyboardAvoidingView,Dimensions, Button, SafeAreaView, Image, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';    
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';    
import { Constants, Location, Permissions } from 'expo';   
import {createDrawerNavigator, DrawerItems} from 'react-navigation';    
import {Header, Left, Icon} from 'native-base';    
import LoginScreen from '../LoginScreen/LoginScreen';    
import SignUpScreen from '../SignUpScreen/SignUpScreen';    
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';`

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window')    
const SCREEN_HEIGHT = height    
const SCREEN_WIDTH = width    
const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height    
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922    
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {    
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  };


  // gets users current location
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      initialPosition: {
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0,
        latitudeDelta: 0,
        longitudeDelta: 0
      },

      markerPosition: {
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0
      }
    }
  }

 watchID = null

    componentDidMount() {

 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {

 var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude)

var long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)

        var initialRegion = {

latitude: lat,            
longitude: long,            
latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,            
longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA

}

 this.setState[{initialPosition: initialRegion}]

 this.setState[{markerPosition: initialRegion}]

 }, (error) => alert(JSON.stringify[error]),

 {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 10000})

    this.watchID = 

navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {

var lat =  parseFloat(position.coords.latitude)

var long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)

 var lastRegion = {

latitude: lat,

 longitude: long,

 longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,

latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA

}

this.setState({initialPosition: lastRegion})
this.setState({markerPosition: lastRegion})

 })

}

 componentWillMount() {

 navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID)

}

  render() {

return (

 <MapView  style = {[style.container, style.map]}

region = {this.state.initialPosition}>

 <Header>

<TouchableOpacity  onPress = {() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer('DrawerOpen')}>

<Ionicons name="ios-menu" size={30} color="#01D56A"/>

</TouchableOpacity>

</Header>

      <MapView.Marker coordinate = {this.state.markerPosition}>


 <View style = {style.radius}> 

<View style = {style.marker}/>

      </View>

      </MapView.Marker>

      <View style = {style.menuSection}>

      </View>

 <AppDrawerNavigator/>

</MapView>

  );

  }

}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },

 text: {
      color: '#fff'

},
  map: {
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    position: 'absolute'
    },

  radius:{

      height: 50,
      width: 50,
      borderRadius: 50 / 2,
      overflow: 'hidden',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(1,213,106,0.3)',
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: 'rgba(1,213,106,0.3)',
      alignItems:'center',
      justifyContent: 'center'
    },

  marker: {
      height: 20,
      width: 20,
      borderWidth: 3,
      borderColor: '#fff',
      borderRadius: 20 / 2,
      borderWidth: 3,
      overflow: 'hidden',
      backgroundColor: '#01D56A'

    },

 menuSection: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)',
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height/3,
  },

// side menu

const CustomDrawerComponent = (props) => (

  <SafeAreaView style = {{flex: 1}}> 

  <View style = {{height: 150, backgroundColor: 'white'} }>

  <DrawerItems {... props} />

    </ScrollView>

  </SafeAreaView>

)

const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({

  Home: HomeScreen
}, {
  contentComponent: CustomDrawerComponent
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.